# LaTex: Pictures in table, caption required

Tags: latex

I have pictures included in a table:

```
\begin{tabular}[h]{|l|l|}
\hline
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{Seite10.eps}  &
\raisebox{1,1cm}[1,1cm][0cm]{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Seite24L.eps}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\newline
```

Now I want captions for those pictures. I know \caption doesn't work out of a float enviroment, so I tried \captionof instead, which didn't work either. I cannot simply write the caption in a cell of the table, because in this case the figure wouldn't feature in the table of figures I want to generate at the end of my file.

I'm grateful for any hint....

Comment: Do you really need a caption per picture, or is a single caption for the whole picture grid sufficient?

Answer (score 4):

To use \captionof load the caption package and use it inside an environment like [minipage](http://texblog.net/help/latex/minipage.html) for instance. It might not work if used directly in a simple table cell.

This example works, using a p cell, so \captionof is called in a [parbox](http://texblog.net/help/latex/minipage.html):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\listoftables

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}[h]{|p{6cm}|l|}
\hline
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{Seite10.eps} \captionof{table}{Test} &
\raisebox{1,1cm}[1,1cm][0cm]{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Seite24L.eps}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\newline
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wanted to lable the individual pictures. So I took them out of the table and used to minipages next to each other, than using the minipage (thanks for the hint!) and captionof. Thank you for taking time to answer my question!

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is a table of figures, try the [subfigure](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/) package.